# What does the state 'drain' mean?

Tags: slurm

When I use `sinfo` I see the following:

```
$ sinfo
PARTITION AVAIL  TIMELIMIT  NODES  STATE NODELIST
[...]
RG3          up 28-00:00:0      1  drain rg3hpc4
[...]
```

What does the state 'drain' mean?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

It means no further job will be scheduled on that node, but the currently running jobs will keep running (by contrast with setting the node `down` which kills all jobs running on the node).

Nodes are often set to that state so that some maintenance operation can take place once all running jobs are finished.

From the [manpage of the scontrol](http://slurm.schedmd.com/scontrol.html) command:

> If you want to remove a node from service, you typically want to set
>   it's state to "DRAIN"

Note that the system administrator most probably gave a reason why the node is drained, and you can see that reason with

```
sinfo -R
```

Comment: To resume a node, this worked for me: `scontrol update nodename=YOURNODEHERE state=resume`